# Track submit event of form with encType=multipart/form-data

Tags: forms, reactjs, enctype

I noticed that the function assigned in the action tag is being evaluated every time the form changes. I want to do something like this to capture form submissions:

```
      <form className='input-form'
        encType='multipart/form-data'
        action={this.getRequestUrl()}
        method='post'
        onSubmit={this.trackFormSubmission()}>
```

but it appears that the trackFormSubmission() is being evaluated on form change as well.

I'm using React.js if that's helpful.

Comment: Typically you'd want to pass a function as a parameter to `onSubmit`, not use it to evaluate a function.  Try `onSubmit={this.trackFormSubmission}`.  I am not 100% sure why the action function is being re-evaluated when the form changes.  That implies that the form is being re-rendered, which typically only happens with a change to state or props, although I am not sure if changing a form will also trigger a re-render.

Comment: You are calling `trackFormSubmission` it directly, so the onSubmit property of the form element becomes whatever you return in `trackFormSubmission`.

Comment: @MichaelParker In case you were curious, the form WAS being re-rendered on change because the state was being modified. I should have known that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `this.trackFormSubmission` every time the `render` method gets called.

You should change

```
onSubmit={this.trackFormSubmission()}>
```

to

```
onSubmit={this.trackFormSubmission}>
```